# Bad request while execute_code in Jupyter Notebook using Jupyter-js-Services

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I`m slightly edit example code from http://jupyter.org/jupyter-js-services/ page for using it React application.

New kernel succesfully started, but request for execute code return Bad Request: 
GET http://localhost/api/kernels/35b235a4-43e9-4452-8cdf-50e92299e7b4/channels?session_id=169c68adb049baaa196454929b152630 400 (Bad Request)

Here is the code:

```
`import { Kernel } from 'jupyter-js-services';
var xmlhttprequest = require('xmlhttprequest');
var ws = require('ws');
global.XMLHttpRequest = xmlhttprequest.XMLHttpRequest;
global.WebSocket = ws;

var ajaxSettings = {};
ajaxSettings['user'] = 'fakeuser';
ajaxSettings['password'] = '$apr1$4ZhnDsjP$YTj6gcQqyf0i4BMW4u028/';

// get info about the available kernels and start a new one
Kernel.getSpecs({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost' }).then(kernelSpecs => {
    console.log('Default spec:', kernelSpecs.default);
    console.log('Available specs', 
    Object.keys(kernelSpecs.kernelspecs));
    // use the default name
    var options = {
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
      wsUrl: 'ws://localhost',
      name: kernelSpecs.default,
      kernelName: 'python3',
      notebookPath: 'try.ipynb',
      ajaxSettings : ajaxSettings
    }
Kernel.startNew(options).then((kernel) => { 
    console.log("CREATED NEW KERNEL: ", kernel);
    var future = kernel.execute({ code: 'a = 1' } );
    future.onDone = () => {
        console.log('Future is fulfilled');
    }
    future.onIOPub = (msg) => {
        console.log(msg.content);  // rich output data
    }
    future.onStdin = (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
    }  });
});`
```

I will be very grateful to any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by editing Nginx configuration like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass            http://localhost:8888;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    # websocket support
    proxy_http_version    1.1;
    proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header      Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout    86400;
  }
  location /notebooks/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
  }

  location /sockjs-node/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```